# How to format or read the javascript files used by Google and Yahoo

Tags: javascript

We know that Google and Yahoo use too much javascript AJAX stuff on their website.
Google specifically use too much in gmail.

I have seen in my website all the js files are readable and anyone can see how i am performing my functions.

i want to know that how can i read the javascript function in js files Google uses.

When i open them they all look very close that i can't even read it.

is there any software or site or any tool which can help me in reading those files

Comment: You can take a look at the minifier libraries that Google and Yahoo have provided to try to understand how they obfuscate: [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) and [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These scripts have been **minified** for bandwidth and obfuscation purposes.

Typically, part of the minifying process is to rename variables to meaningless names like `a`. It is not possible to regain the original names to make the code meaningful.

Instead, ask the developer whether (s)he is happy to provide you with a copy of his/her original code.

Comment: ..Or find the exact minifier/obfuscator they used and de-minify! :)

Comment: @jerluc: No, you still cannot recreate the original information from nothing. Basic fact of the laws of physics.

Comment: @jerluc: I don't understand your reference.

Comment: http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ (jQuery uses this stuff to minify + obfuscate their code)

Comment: @jerluc It's not about finding the right de-minifier. You can easily beautify minified and obfuscated code, but the problem is that all the function and variables have been renamed with very short names. It would be _easier_ to read than a raw JS from Google, but hardly semantic when you're dealing with functions a, b, c and d instead of (for example) showPopup, loadLabel, updateMail and saveSettings.

Comment: @jerluc: What @Tomalak means that, of course you can format the code so that it becomes more readable, but the variables (and also methods) will stay meaninglessly 'a', 'b', 'c',... Expressive variable and method names are a crucial part for understanding code. Of course you can try to understand code by having a look at the implementation of the methods, but this takes time...

Comment: "Obfuscation" has __never__ referred to only a one-way "hashing" of component terms; it is more or less a form of one-way or two-way encryption

Comment: @jerluc: What are you talking about?

Comment: @jerluc, jQuery uses uglify.js. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/Makefile#L9

Comment: If a Javascript method originally named `showWindow()` becomes obfuscated as `a()` how is it that at a later time--after the obfuscated code is interpreted by the browser--you can still manually invoke the method `showWindow()` rather than having to invoke `a()`? It is plainly because the obfuscated code retains the reference to the original names for the sake of not breaking any external references to these component terms. Otherwise, obfuscated code would be completely useless (at least for Javascript)

Comment: @katspaugh very interesting actually. I wonder if they had used /packer/ historically..

Comment: @jerluc: The calls to native Javascript functions, sure. But the _vast majority_ of symbols will be internal calls and internal variables, whose names will no longer have any meaning... A minute ago you were claiming that that meaning could be recreated after obfuscation.

Comment: Have you even tried the link I sent at all? There is plainly a __Decode__ button to decode Javascript that was obfuscated originally using packer. The only way this is possible is by retaining the internal symbols in more or less a symbol table so that no external references break.

Comment: @jerluc, yes, they used to minify with Packer until as late as 1.4 release. Not very long ago, actually!

Comment: @jerluc: I'm not sure how else I can say it. You cannot get back data that was lost. It's a physical impossibility. If the original symbol names are kept in the code, even if moved out to a separate storage location, then that's not full obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste that code into Visual Studio (you can get Visual Web Developer Express for free), then use document formatting feature (Ctrl+k, Ctrl+d) to let it format the script for you. But don't forget that as @Tomalak Geret'kal has said, these scripts are both minified (compressed) and obfuscated. Therefore, reverse engineering is not that much possible.